# Convertir imagen a Base64 en android

Tags: java, android, base64, bitmap

Estoy tratando de convertir una imagen en Base64, esto para enviar al servidor ya que es un requerimiento de este, mi problema esta al generar el Base64 utilizo una función creada por mi para convertir cualquier File en Base64 y con archivos PDF funciona bien, el problema esta en la imágenes, que al tratar de volver a convertirlas, el Base64 no genera imagen al hacer la conversión

La funcion que utilizo es la siguiente

```
public static String generateBase64File(File file) {
    int size = (int) file.length();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        fis.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

El formato resultante es el siguiente para imágenes

```
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
```

Si copian y pegan en algún generador de imágenes Base64 no muestra nada, como podría solucionar esto??

Comment: Cual es un ejemplo del generador de imágenes Base64 que estas usando?

Comment: @Jorgesys Selecciono una imagen desde mi movil, sea PNG o JPG, para verificar el base64 utilizo estas paginas https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter y https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image y para hacer la conversión esta https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image, el resultado obtenido por estas paginas es totalmente diferente al generado por la funcion que he compartido

Comment: Si obtienes el valor en base64 recuerda que debes agregar al inicio "data:image/png;base64,", revisa mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El convertir la imagen a base 64 y lo puedes realizar de esta forma, como ejemplo este mètodo:

```
private static final String BASE = "data:image/png;base64,";
private String imagetoBase64 = "";

private void convertImagetoBase64(){
   
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.githubmascot);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
            byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
            // Get the Base64 string
            String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            return imgString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            imagetoBase64 = BASE + s;               
            Log.i(TAG, "ImagetoBase64 : " +BASE + s);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

en tu caso  puede ser que no estas obteniendo el valor completo de la imagen o que no estas agregando **al inicio el valor  `data:image/png;base64,` esto es importante para visualizar correctamente la imagen** :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si deseas obtener la imagen en base 64 a partir de un objeto File, este es un mètod que recibe el objeto y obtiene la imagen en base 64:

```
private static final String BASE = "data:image/png;base64,";
private String imagetoBase64 = "";

private void convertImagetoBase64(File file){

    String filePath = file.getPath();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
            byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
            // Get the Base64 string
            String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            return imgString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            imagetoBase64 = BASE + s;
            editText.setText(BASE + s);
            Log.i(TAG, "ImagetoBase64 : " +BASE + s);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Para este ejemplo usas ´´´bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.githubmascot);´´´ en mi caso lo que hago es obtenerla desde una opcion que me permite seleccionar desde la camara o galeria y de esa forma obtengo un archivo, de la forma en como muestras si resulta pero con una imagen del resource y no externa

Comment: Si tienes un objeto File, para obtener el bitmap usa:  String filePath = file.getPath();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath); He editado la respuesta.